# Unable to fix "ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, linear-regression

I was asked to write a program for Linear Regression with the following steps.

1. Load the R data set mtcars as a pandas dataframe.
2. Build another linear regression model by considering the log of independent variable wt, and log of dependent variable mpg.
3. Fit the model with data, and display the R-squared value

I am a beginner at Statistics with Python.

I have tried getting the log values without converting to a new DataFrame but that gave an error saying "TypeError: 'OLS' object is not subscriptable"

```
import statsmodels.api as sa
import statsmodels.formula.api as sfa
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cars = sa.datasets.get_rdataset("mtcars")
cars_data = cars.data
lin_mod1 = sfa.ols("wt~mpg",cars_data)
lin_mod2 = pd.DataFrame(lin_mod1)
lin_mod2['wt'] = np.log(lin_mod2['wt'])
lin_mod2['mpg'] = np.log(lin_mod2['mpg'])
lin_res1 = lin_mod2.fit()
print(lin_res1.summary())
```

The expected result is the table after linear regression but the actual output is an error

> [ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('mtcars')
mtcars_data = mtcars.data
liner_model = sm.formula.ols('np.log(wt) ~ np.log(mpg)',mtcars_data)
liner_result = liner_model.fit()
print(liner_result.rsquared)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You're a lifesaver! The program worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I broke your code and I've ran it line by line.
The problem is here:

```
 lin_mod1 = sfa.ols("wt~mpg",cars_data)
```

If you try to print it, the output is:

```
 statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS object at 0x7f1c64273eb8
```

And it can't be interpreted correctly to build a data frame.

The solution is to get the result of the first linear model into a table and the finally put into a data frame:

```
results = lin_mod1.fit()
results_summary = results.summary()
```

If you print the results_summary you will see the variables are: Intercept and mpg.
I don't if it's an error of concept or what, since it's not the pair "wt"-"mpg".

```
 # summary as a html table
 results_as_html = results_summary.tables[1].as_html()

 # dataframe from the html table
 lin_mod2 = pd.read_html(results_as_html, header=0, index_col=0)[0]
```

The print of lin_mod2 is:

```
  coef      std       err       t     P>|t|  [0.025  0.975]
  Intercept  6.0473    0.309  19.590    0.0   5.417   6.678
  mpg       -0.1409    0.015  -9.559    0.0  -0.171  -0.111
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Unfortunately, it didn't evaluate as wt was not there. Anyway, thank you so much for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import numpy as np

cars=sm.datasets.get_rdataset("mtcars")
cars_data=cars.data
lin_mod1=smf.ols('np.log(wt)~np.log(mpg)',cars_data)
lin_model_fit=lin_mod1.fit()
print(lin_model_fit.summary())
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
lin_mod2 = pd.DataFrame(lin_mod1)
```

To:

```
lin_mod2 = pd.DataFrame(data = lin_mod1)
```